# Worker Lost Error after task accepted with exitcode 2

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I am new to celery. I have added the backup script to celery using periodic_task. From the logs I see that `"Task accepted: main"` after immediately I see the below error in the logs.

```
[2017-09-21 06:01:00,257: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'PoolWorker-5' pid:XXXX
exited with 'exitcode 2'

[2017-09-21 06:01:00,268: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 2.',)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1224, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 2.
```

Thanks in advance.